# Is this the proper way to wrap a third-party library as an Angular.js service?

Tags: angularjs, svg

I'm trying to wrap Snap.svg as a service of my application. The code below works, but is this the right way to go about it?

```
var svgService = angular.module("svgService", []);

svgService.factory("svgService", [
  function () {
    if (Snap) {
      return Snap;
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `if` check would throw an `ReferenceError: Snap is not defined` error anyway if the `Snap` doesn't exist.

You could replace the condition statement like this to be safe:

```
if (typeof Snap !== 'undefined') {
```

or if the `Snap` is in `window`, just reference it directly:

```
if (window.Snap) {
```

and even better, at least when it come to unit testing, using a built-in `$window` service as it allow you to mock it out.

```
svgService.factory("svgService", function ($window) {
  // the if check is unnecessary since an undefined
  // is returned anyway when the Snap doesn't exist.
  return $window.Snap; 
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this response. if (typeof Snap !== "undefined") {} is virtually identical to if (Snap) {}; the point is that neither does anything if Snap contains a falsey value.